# Invalid column when adding a foreginkey

Tags: entity-framework-core

```
public class PIC
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IMONumber")]
    public int IMONumber { get; set; }

    public string VesselName { get; set; }

    public string PICOperation { get; set; }

    public string PICChartering { get; set; }
}

public class VesselInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImoType { get; set; }
    public int IMONumber { get; set; }
    public PIC PIC { get; set; }
}
```

When I call following:

```
var test1 = db.Vessels.ToList();
or
var test2 = db.Vessels.Include(p=>p.PIC).ToList();
```

I get an error saying PICId invalid column? And opointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will recommend this:
Your PIC class is not connected with a foreign key your VeselInfo table so they are not related and you cannot get information about that. Try replacing your code and try again

```
public class PIC
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    public int IMONumber { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IMONumber")]
    public virtual IMON IMON

    public string VesselName { get; set; }

    public string PICOperation { get; set; }

    public string PICChartering { get; set; }
}

public class VesselInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImoType { get; set; }
    public int IMONumber { get; set; }
    public int PicId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("PicId")]
    public virtual PIC PIC { get; set; }
}
```